# Testing Stripe payment, event.preventDefault() seems to be ignored

Tags: stripe-payments

I am following a course on creating an e-commerce site.
We use these stripe templates: https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js

Put all together, we have the following:

```
<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
<style>
.StripeElement {
box-sizing: border-box;

height: 40px;

padding: 10px 12px;

border: 1px solid transparent;
border-radius: 4px;
background-color: white;

box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 #e6ebf1;
-webkit-transition: box-shadow 150ms ease;
transition: box-shadow 150ms ease;
}

.StripeElement--focus {
box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 #cfd7df;
}

.StripeElement--invalid {
border-color: #fa755a;
}

.StripeElement--webkit-autofill {
background-color: #fefde5 !important;
}
</style>
<div class="col-10 col-md-6 mx-auto">
  <h3>Add Payment method</h3>
  <form action="/charge" method="post" id="payment-form">
    <div class="form-row">
      <div id="card-element" class="form-control">
        <!-- A Stripe Element will be inserted here. -->
      </div>

      <!-- Used to display form errors. -->
      <div id="card-errors" role="alert"></div>
    </div>

    <button class="btn btn-primary my-3">Submit Payment</button>
  </form>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
// Create a Stripe client.
var stripe = Stripe('pk_test_XB5GjoA0WlBvhBTnI01QRHP400ZKyL3x0U');

// Create an instance of Elements.
var elements = stripe.elements();

// Custom styling can be passed to options when creating an Element.
// (Note that this demo uses a wider set of styles than the guide below.)
var style = {
base: {
  color: '#32325d',
  fontFamily: '"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif',
  fontSmoothing: 'antialiased',
  fontSize: '16px',
  '::placeholder': {
    color: '#aab7c4'
  }
},
invalid: {
  color: '#fa755a',
  iconColor: '#fa755a'
}
};

// Create an instance of the card Element.
var card = elements.create('card', {style: style});

// Add an instance of the card Element into the `card-element` <div>.
card.mount('#card-element');

// Handle real-time validation errors from the card Element.
card.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
var displayError = document.getElementById('card-errors');
if (event.error) {
  displayError.textContent = event.error.message;
} else {
  displayError.textContent = '';
}
});

// Handle form submission.
var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
event.preventDefault();

stripe.createToken(card).then(function(result) {
  if (result.error) {
    // Inform the user if there was an error.
    var errorElement = document.getElementById('card-errors');
    errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;
  } else {
    // Send the token to your server.
    stripeTokenHandler(result.token);
  }
});
});

// Submit the form with the token ID.
function stripeTokenHandler(token) {
// Insert the token ID into the form so it gets submitted to the server
var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
var hiddenInput = document.createElement('input');
hiddenInput.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
hiddenInput.setAttribute('name', 'stripeToken');
hiddenInput.setAttribute('value', token.id);
form.appendChild(hiddenInput);

// Submit the form
form.submit();
}
</script>
```

When I submit the form, I expected the preventDefault action to kick in. However, the form is submitted instead of me getting a token as in the example.
Have I missed something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The form submission is prevented by default, but then called explicitly using `form.submit()` near the bottom of your JavaScript.

This is actually intended and you do eventually want to submit your form. You'll notice that this will create the token, then create a hidden input field on your form with the value of the token, then it'll submit the form. That form submission sends all of the details input into your form plus the value of the hidden input containing the token.

In this case the `event.preventDefault()` is working properly and not submitting the form until you later call `form.submit()`.